# Finding minimal element in array, and its index

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

With OpenMP 3.1, it is possible to have a `reduction` clause with `min`:

```
double m;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(min:m)
for (int i=0;i< n; i++){ 
  if (a[i]*2 < m) {
    m = a[i] * 2;
} 
return m;
```

Suppose I also need the *index* of the minimal element; is there a way to use the `reduction` clause for this? I believe the alternative is writing the reduction manually using `nowait` and `critical`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Suppose I also need the index of the minimal element; is there a way to use the reduction clause for this?

Unfortunately, no. the list of possible reductions in OpenMP is very … small. In particular, `min` and `max` are the only “higher-level” functions and they aren’t customisable. At all.

I have to admit that I don’t like OpenMP’s approach to reductions, precisely because it’s not extensible in the slightest, it is *designed* only to work on special cases. Granted, those are interesting special cases but it’s still fundamentally a bad approach.

For such operations, you need to implement the reduction yourself by accumulating thread-local results into thread-local variables and combining them at the end.

The easiest way of doing this (and indeed quite close to how OpenMP implements reductions) is to have an array with elements for each thread, and using `omp_get_thread_num()` to access an element. Note however that this will lead to a performance degradation due to false sharing if the elements in the array share a cache line. To mitigate this, pad the array:

```
struct min_element_t {
    double min_val;
    size_t min_index;
};

size_t const CACHE_LINE_SIZE = 1024; // for example.
std::vector<min_element_t> mins(threadnum * CACHE_LINE_SIZE);

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    size_t const index = omp_get_thread_num() * CACHE_LINE_SIZE;
    // operate on mins[index] …
}
```

Comment: @user1071136 No, I mean `omp_get_thread_num`. We want the *index*, not the total number. And as for `threadnum`, that’s a placeholder. You cannot use `omp_get_num_threads` here since you’re not inside a parallel region. Instead, you should actually pass `numthread` as the number of threads in the subsequent parallel clause.

Comment: +1 for mentioning false sharing. Still, OpenMP reduction clauses were designed for efficiency and easy implementation, not for extensibiliy.

Comment: We could use `omp_get_max_threads()` to know how much storage to allocate in advance, couldn't we? Also, as for `CACHE_LINE_SIZE`, it doesn't seem to have a big difference for me, so I'm probably not trying the right values. For a cache line of 64bytes, should we use "4" ?

Comment: @user1071136 Yes, you can. As for `CACHE_LINE_SIZE`, the size here should be the size of the cache line in bytes. So in your case, 64, *not* 4. The value 1024 was actually stolen from the parallel extension of the GCC standard library implementation. They hard-coded a large value to be more or less independent of the actual machine, playing it safe. Since the memory size is negligible anyway, going for a bigger size is probably OK.